# Two Astable NE555 Affects one another

Tags: 555

I have two separate breadboards, on each breadboard I placed NE555 and both are configured in astable mode. Breadboard 1 is configured to 200Hz @ 50% duty cycle and Breadboard 2 is configured to 1.8Khz @ 50% duty cycle. Each breadboard is tested separately and measured with oscilloscope and the output of both is perfect. Now when the two breadboards are connected to the same battery 12v 7AH, the output of breadboard 1 changes to 1.2khz with fluctuating duty cycle while output of breadboard 2 stays at 1.8Khz and 50% DC, but if the breadboards are connected to different batteries, the output is OK, that is breadboard 1 gives 200Hz and breadboard 2 gives 1.8Khz. The problem only happens when both breadboards are connected to the same battery, and the circuit will be powered from only one source. Please, this is strange, I've not seen it before, please I need help.

Comment: Where are your decoupling capacitors?

Comment: I agree with the others, it sounds like a lack of decent decoupling capacitance. This will be made worse if you have chosen large C's and small R's in your 555 timing circuit. So fixing it might be revising your RC values as well as adding decoupling. Please do post your circuit.

Comment: Yes... I did not use any decoupling capacitor because I don't even know they exist, after reading your comments, I Googled it and I saw a simple schematic and I tried it and it worked....... Thanks brothers..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me like you have not decoupled the two systems properly. What decoupling capacitors do you have in place? And, equally important, where are they?

Based on what you've said there, you should have at least a 100nF across the power pins of each chip, as physically close to each IC as possible. I would also say that a large bulk decoupler (say 10uF) would be a good idea to fully stabilise them, you could put a single cap next to the battery.

No doubt someone with more time will be able to write a good detailed description of decoupling practices, but a quick internet search for "decoupling practices" would tell you a lot, as would "why do we need to decouple ICs?"

Comment: I don't know of decoupling capacitor, I just Googled it now and I saw how to to it. I don't have such in my circuit, I will include them now and get back to you with the performance.... Thanks for the answer

Comment: Worked like charm...... Hahahaha hahahaha.... I've suffered on this for long.. .. Thanks man... You made my day...